# can we use C#.NET to consume a VB dll (API)

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i have a requirement where i have to use a tools API which is VB dll and i have to do some insert ,delete and update using that API. Can i use C#.net to implement these functionalities.If i use vb dll as reference and use thode API's will i face any issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not, you should be able to consume it without any problems.

Comment: I read "Can we use C# to consume a VB dll" followed by "Absolutely not." lol :o :o

Answer (score 3):

If it is VB.NET DLL, and as long as it exposes only CLS-compliant types, then you will have no trouble at all.

If these are VB 6 components, as opposed to VB.NET, then you will sometimes find strangeness when dealing with some types like variants.  At least that was what I experienced when doing this.

Comment: Even if that DLL is .net dll then also a .net framework version issue is there.
VB6.0 DLL - it must be deployed using regsvr tool.

Comment: I believe .NET 3.5 apps can consume .NET DLLs of older .NET versions, etc., and yes VB6 components use regsvr32

Answer (score 1):

It will work without problems.

Only issue you may face are methods with optional arguments. For them you will just need to fill all parameters and not only mandatory ones.